# How to Set (and get as well) Minimum server Memory and Maximum server Memory of a SQL Server Instance using T-SQL Query

Tags: sql-server, sql, ssms

I want to set Minimum and Maximum server Memory for a SQL Server using T-SQL. I am able to do it using SSMS->Object Explorer->Server Properties but don't know how to do it using T-SQL commands. 
Along with this, also can anyone help me out with how to set 'Processor Affinity' using T-SQL commands ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

To find the current values, take a look at the `sys.configurations` system view. Like so:

```
select * from sys.configurations
where name in ('min server memory (MB)', 'max server memory (MB)')
```

To change one or both of those values, use `sp_configure`. You'll also need to call `reconfigure` afterwards for the new setting to take effect. Like so:

```
exec sp_configure 'max server memory (MB)', 10240; -- 10 Gb
reconfigure;
```